# How to serve a local website under a global domain using a proxy?

Tags: web-services, deployment

Some time ago I saw a paid (IIRC) service that allowed to serve a local website under a global subdomain like *shadow-zombies-1234.coolservice.com*.

If I remember correctly it was about running some program on the local machine, which was connecting to their server and establishing a tunnel for the HTTP traffic. So if you sent `GET /` to *shadow-zombies-1234.coolservice.com*, that request was proxied to the local server.

I don't remember the name of the service and I cannot find it now, so I need your help.

PS. Not sure if this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow but neither Superuser nor Server Fault seem to be 100% good fits..

EDIT: I'm not trying to make a custom solution, I just forgot the name of the service and cannot find it on google. I guess there could be more than one of them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I received an answer from someone who doesn't have enough reputation to post it here himself (many thanks!):*

You are referring to localtunnel.com, which is no longer available.
See
http://progrium.com/blog/2012/12/25/localtunnel-v2-available-in-beta/

The project https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel is currently down, so you can use
https://ngrok.com/

There are also http://localtunnel.me/ and https://meetfinch.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Thomasz, I'm not quite sure what problem you're trying to solve. Hopefully this helps:

In order for a site to be visible globally, it must be have an external IP and, probably, DNS name.

If that IP is the address of a proxy, the server can be told to satisfy the request by passing it on to another server. If the proxying server has a tunnel or non-public interface as well as the public interface, the actual server can be non-public.

I can't see anything obvious with a quick search, but you could perhaps look into a low-cost or free AWS or similar server to host the proxy and a VPN tunnel to the actual host?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use something that already works, see the edit I've just made.